# Obj-c exporting .h files for a Static Library - don't want to expose class definition

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries

I am struggling to create an iOS static library correctly/cleanly.

So far I have used Extension a to create a separation between my internal (private) .h declarations and the public .h declaration (that gets exported).

I have "successfully" created the library and seen it working. However I am still exposing the class declaration in the public WTDevice.h

```
@interface WTDevice : NSObject <WTMinorStateDelegate,CBPeripheralDelegate>
```

As WTDevice inherits from WTMinorStateDelegate I have to export protocol WTMinorStateDelegate too, which I don't wish todo as this is only used within the library.

BTW the WTDevice extension is in WTDevice_internal.h which doesn't get exported.

I am sure there is a way of putting the line:

```
@interface WTDevice : NSObject <WTMinorStateDelegate,CBPeripheralDelegate>
```

into WTDevice.m (making it private), however I have failed so far. The question is what replaces it when I remove it from the WTDevice.h file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WTDevice.m add this before the @implementation block to create a private category.

```
@interface WTDevice () <WTMinorStateDelegate>
@end
```

In WTDevice.h remove WTMinorStateDelegate from the @interface line.

Comment: Slight pedantic note, the usual terminology for an anonymous category like that is "class extension".

Comment: One side effect of this change are lots of warnings! To fix them I now have to explicitly cast WTDevice objects when they are used as a parameter to a method taking (id<WTMinorStateDelegate>). As I suppose the compile cannot tell that a WTDevice is also a <WTMinorStateDelegate> as I have removed this info from the WTDevice.h  a minor issue. Thanks again.